# Windows Explorer Edit Remote Like Fuse

Tags: ssh, windows-explorer, sftp

I'm a Linux user attempting to move to Windows.

Normally I use Fuse (gvfs-fuse) on a Debian build which allows the file manager to open remote locations (centos servers), which allows me to edit remote files using a locally installed editor (Sublime).

I don't want to use a separate client (ftp or winscp), and I don't have any ports open except SSH and HTTP on the servers (I use SFTP, xfer over SSH). Also, I don't want to dual-boot.

So I'm wanting the same workflow via Windows Explorer..

..I tried "Swish" - but that seems to just save the file locally.

..I tried "WinFsp" with "SSHFS" but I can't navigate in it, or edit files.

..I tried "Dokan" and variants but I can't seem to get those working either.

Maybe I'm not setting those up correctly and could use direct instruction on getting them going (note I'm not versed in Windows lingo).

..

What is a simple way to use Explorer to show remote files, that allows a local editor to edit them?

I'd prefer an Explorer hack over installing something if possible, but if something needs to be installed, I'd prefer it to be minor and transparent - and apparently would need plain instruction on getting it going.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving it with "SSHFS-Win".

```
SSHFS-Win is a minimal port of SSHFS to Windows. Under the hood it uses Cygwin for the POSIX environment and WinFsp for the FUSE functionality.
```

https://github.com/billziss-gh/sshfs-win

I had a hard time getting the path to work from the examples on the page, here's what I ended up using in case it helps others:

In a .bat file I put:

```
@echo off
net use X: \\sshfs\root@94.51.28.15!2222\..\var\www S0meP455.
exit
```

That's a fictitious example mapping the remote location to drive X using root and port 2222.. You'd use whatever you normally log into SSH with.. You don't have to put the pass in the file, you can use "*" (splat) instead to be prompted for a pass. You don't have to use a .bat file, you can just use the "net use" line - but if you connect often it's easier in a file.

To disconnect, just right-click the mapped location and choose "disconnect" (also kills process).

Now I can edit the files "in place" instead of transferring them (helpful in development).